# AddRow Dynamically to any Google.Visualization

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables, google-visualization

I have an **accounts** array containing 5 objects

I want to loop through those object and **add** a row/column to my **ColumnChart** Google Chart. I've tried, but I don't see any effect

```
<script>

      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultSeries);

      function drawMultSeries() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['max_up', 'cpe_mac_up', 'cpe_guaranty_up', 'cpe_guaranty_down', 'cpe_mac_down','max_down', { role: 'annotation' } ],
              ['1000', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, ''],
              ['10001', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16,233],
              ['1002', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']
            ]);

            //I'm trying to make a loop here
            for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                //console.log(accounts[i].account_id);
                data.addRow[accounts[i].account_id, 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']

            }

            var options = {
              width: 600,
              height: 400,
              legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
              bar: { groupWidth: '15%' },
              isStacked: true,
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
              document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
          }

  </script>

_
```

---

**Result**

[image]

---

Any hints / suggestion on this will be much appreciated !

---

**Update**

Thanks to Simon found the bug on this line

`data.addRow(['accounts[i].account_id', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']);`

Now my graph look like this

[image]

Nothing is displaying

Comment: Maybe you could provide some details of any errors?  Console warnings?  A first glance would suggest that `data.addRow[ ... ]` should be `data.addRow( ... )` - i.e. parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: No error in the console, but if I take out `['1000', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, ''],
              ['10001', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16,233],
              ['1002', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']` The graph won't load anymore.

Comment: Good call trying it now. :)

Comment: Right, you need the brackets as well, as this Google API takes an array.

Comment: They complain that I need a string on the first element, then, I've tried `data.addRow(['accounts[i].account_id', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']);`

Comment: My graph now look wired. I'll upload it

Comment: So far, you're correct about everything.

Comment: Check out this answer: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281326/google-line-chart-adding-array-of-objects/33291560#33291560), maybe it helps.

Comment: `data.addRow([accounts[i].account_id.toString(), 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']);`

Comment: Work perfectly. Thanks for helping me out on this.

Comment: Good good.  I've posted it as an answer, in case you want to close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

`data.addRow[accounts[i].account_id, 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']`

needs to be:

`data.addRow([accounts[i].account_id.toString(), 28, 19, 29, 30, 12,'']);`

as per the comments :)

Comment: I suspect that syntax isn't quite right.  If you include a header row as part of the array the docs say that you should include a second boolean parameter of `false` to indicate that the first row is not data: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#arraytodatatable

Comment: Got it now. My bad. Thanks for your assistant on this. :)

Comment: You don't have to add `false` as second parameter. 

The documentation says: "Default is false."